# Express session not persisting after JQuery Get Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, express-session

I am trying to save this variable called `server` from the user. After they submit, they go to another page. On that page, I verify their `server` exists and if not send them back.

The session is saved when I run the post request because I immediately check via the get request if it exists (via client-side). However, if I refresh my page, the session is no longer defined and the user is sent back home (verified this with the logs). I think it is something **cookie** related, but I could not seem to get it to work.

Here is my **sesssions.js** route:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));

router.get('/check', (req, res) => {
    let sesh = req.session;
    console.log("Checking server exists: " + sesh.server);
    res.send(sesh.server);
});

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let sesh = req.session;
    sesh.server = req.body.server;
    console.log("Setting server:  " + sesh.server);
    res.send(sesh.server);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is how are the requests which both return promises:

```
function setSession(value) {
    return $.post("/sessions/login", { 'server': value }).then();
}

function getSession() {
    return $.get("/sessions/check").then();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution from a friend. You cannot instantiate middleware in a route. Just had to move the middleware instantiation to app.js.